# What uniquely identifies a constraint in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, constraints, data-dictionary

Within the Oracle documentation, the (DBA|ALL|USER)_CONSTRAINTS view has the following columns (among others)

- `OWNER` Owner of the constraint definition
- `CONSTRAINT_NAME` Name of the constraint definition
- `TABLE_NAME` Name associated with the table (or view) with constraint definition

My question is which of these columns uniquely identifies a constraint?  Is it just `OWNER` and `CONSTRAINT_NAME` indicating that the constraint name must be unique within the scope of that `OWNER` schema, or is it `OWNER`, `TABLE_NAME`, and `CONSTRAINT_NAME` indicating that the constraint name must only be unique within the scope of that `OWNER.TABLE_NAME`?

Comment: Do you have a test Oracle database available where you can try creating constraints with the same name on different tables and see if you encounter an ORA-02264 error (constraint naming conflict)?

Comment: I have read-only access to the Oracle database, so I don't believe that I have permission to create a constraint there.  With the ORA-02264 error, I was able to find an article by Burleson Consulting, however, it wasn't helpful because he states "Make sure that you have not already used this constraint_name in another table." which makes it sound like it must be unique to the schema, but then he goes on to say "Choose another constraint name, unique to the table." which indicates that it is unique to the `OWNER.TABLENAME`, so I'm still at a loss.

Comment: With the ORA-02264 error, I found an answer here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279973/sql-error-name-already-used-by-an-existing-constraint A constraint is uniquely identified by `OWNER` and `CONSTRAINT_NAME`, meaning that the `CONSTRAINT_NAME` must be unique within the schema.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

> Each of the following schema objects has its own namespace:
>
> - Constraints

Which suggests, that uniquely identifiyng the constraint is it's name and the schema/owner of the constraint.

One point here - it depends what you consider 'unique'.

Let's consider you have a constraint. You will drop the constraint and recreate it with different definition. The constraint has still the same name, but it has a different `OBJECT_ID` from the database point of view - it is a different object.
It is still unique from the point of current state of the database, but not for the lifetime of it. So, if you want to make sure that you're still working with the same constraint (not only constrain with the same name as before), you might want to query `OBJECT_ID.DBA/ALL/USER_OBJECTS` instead.